# Can't load more post items after WordPress and WPBakery update

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently made a WordPress update and now I have the problem that the page contents are all displayed correctly, but only 6 entries are listed in my blog and I cannot scroll any further using the "Load more" button.

However, I have not yet been able to find the exact cause, so I'll list what I think could cause problems:

- Updated WordPress from version 5.4 to 5.6.2
- I use WPBakery to create the pages and blog entries and have updated the plugin from 4.8 to 6.6
- Changed from PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.4 on the server
- SSL certificate installed at the provider and then changed the WordPress address and the website address to https in the WP settings
- Used the "Better Search Replace" plugin to change all URLs from http to https across the entire page
- In the wp-config.php I added the switch define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true); as the first line

The problem is, as I said, that only 6 posts are displayed and when I click on "Load more" nothing seems to happen, i.e. no error is displayed. I suspect that an AJAX call is supposed to be made here and it either goes nowhere or does not find any further posts, although there are actually 10 more.

I don't know if it helps, but here is the output from the developer console in the browser:

```
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/345170787868762112?&lang=en&callback=twitterFetcher.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd=0.4784765365216228' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
close.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {"status":"Nothing found"}
    at Function.se.error (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at se.tokenize (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at se.select (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at Function.se (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at Function.s.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2)
    at S.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at s.fn.init.S.fn.init (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at new s.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2)
    at S (jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1:2)
    at vcGridStyleLoadMore.addItems (vc_grid.min.js?ver=6.6.0:10)
util.js:224 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
LA.j @ util.js:224
util.js:224 Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
LA.j @ util.js:224
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/bower/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.min.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

Unfortunately, I don't know where to start at the moment.

Comment: Hi, got the same problem. Did you fixed it?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it: there is a table vl_postmeta. This contains a data record with the meta_key = "_vc_post_settings". The meta_value field contains a serialized array with settings and this contained the entry max_items with the value 9. I just changed that.

Comment: change to what? thanks! same problem for me :)